# configuring outlook for Dynamics CRM - how do I verify my onmicrosoft.com email address?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am having problems with the outlook configuration wizard for Dynamics CRM.
When I click TEST Connection I get a message
"Cannot connect to Microsoft Dynamics CRM server because we cannot authenticate your credentials. Check our connection or contact your administrator for morehelp."

The problem is documented at 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2666080

The cause of this issue is due to not having your Windows Live ID verified. When you sign up for a Windows Live ID and you are not using a @hotmail.com or a @live.com email address, you will need to verify the e-mail address before it can be used to configure the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Client for Outlook.

However the KB does not explain how I get the onmicrosoft.com email address verified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hav'nt had this issue myself, but it sounds like you created a Live Id with a non-Microsoft Email Address, e.g. kirsten@kirstenscompany.com. You need to log into that Email Address (kirsten@kirstenscompany.com) and find the email from Microsoft and click the verification link - as is common in many registration processes.

This is actually described in the knowledge base article *you* linked under the 'Resolution' section.

> After the creation of your Windows Live ID, an email is sent to the
>   email address you created as your Windows Live ID. You will need to
>   login to that email account and click on the link in the email to
>   verify the email address. Once that is complete, you will be able to
>   continue the configuration of the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Client for
>   Outlook.

There's a good chance that link will time out after a while, in which case I would log into the Live Id account on the Microsoft Website, this should probably allow you to get another verification link.

Comment: I assume the email address we are talking about is the one that the set up for the dynamics CRM trial suggested.  i.e myname@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com
I dont know how to get in to read this email.  I dont recall seeing any instructions.
Some instructions were sent to my proper email address, but they did not include how to use or validate this email address.

Comment: Have you tried logging into hotmail with it? You just go through one of the live id sites e.g. https://login.live.com

Comment: I can get into the microsoft account that way, and send a verification email.  BUT I dont know how to get into email to receive the verification email

Comment: Is the address you signed up with an actual email address? E.g. If I was creating a Live Id but wanted to use a Yahoo Email Address, I would have to sign into Yahoo to validate it. If the address you signed up with isnt a real email address then you wont be able to verify.